# Error: Variable 'int' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to show all the files connected to the comment. There are models of **Files** and **Comments**.

```
  @{       
  if (Model.Comments != null && Model.Comments.Any())  
  {
            <br/>
            foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
            {
                @comment.title <br />

                @comment.type <br />
                @comment.content <br />
                @comment.timestamp <br />
                @comment.ApplicationUser <br />
                if (Model.Files.FirstOrDefault().CommentID != null && Model.Files.Any())
                {
                    <br />
                    foreach (var file in Model.Comments.FirstOrDefault().Files.FirstOrDefault().CommentID)
                    {

                        <a href="@file.path">
                            @file.name
                        </a>
                        <br />
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    <label>No File(s) to Download</label>
                }
                <hr />
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <label>No Comment(s)</label>
        }
    }
```

This line

```
foreach (var file in Model.Comments.FirstOrDefault().Files.FirstOrDefault().CommentID)
```

throws an error: *foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'int' because 'int' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'*.

How could this be fixed?

Comment: foreach (var file in Model.Comments.FirstOrDefault().Files.ToList())

Comment: you are selecting FirstOrDefault().CommentID then why foreach loop ?

Comment: because there can be more than one file

Comment: yes then use Model.Comments.FirstOrDefault().Files.ToList()

Comment: try my answer hopefully it will work

Comment: ToList() does not show anything, shows No file(s) to download

Comment: ok that means your error is resolved .

Comment: That was an error - is shows that there are no files, but there is a file

Comment: Now you need to see why your Model.Comments.FirstOrDefault().Files not get populated . Please try to debug and see if you have files attached to it

Comment: hi as per the code the You are taking FirstOrDefault() i.e first records from comments table and then reading files object ourt of it and running loop on that . did you check on debuger that Model.Comments.FirstOrDefault().Files has records ?

Comment: No :( still not showing files

Comment: so I think your code is right . Can you please check for which comments you have files attached to it and then use  Model.Comments.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Id=idofcommentwhichasfile).Files.ToList()

Comment: I am getting this on the IF line for past 20 mins:
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_sgfhvmhr.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: h i can you share you model structure . please . It seems you only have issues which ne to use if Models.Files is a property then why you are chekcing Model.Comment.FirstOrDefault() in If statement . Please again check what you want to shoose . Model.Files or Model.Comments.Files?

Comment: In IF I want to check if there are any files added to a comment (commentID)

Comment: if ( Model  !=null &&  Model.Files.FirstOrDefault().CommentID != null && Model.Files.Any())

Comment: always check if model is not null then if it has files and then check commentid this way you dont have errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
because you want to loop throught the list of file you need to use below .

 foreach (var file in Model.Comments.FirstOrDefault().Files.ToList())
                {

                    <a href="@file.path">
                        @file.name
                    </a>
                    <br />
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
   $.each(Model.Comments.FirstOrDefault().Files.ToList(), function (i, item) {
                       <a href="@file.path">
                            @item.name
                        </a>
                        <br />
                    });
```